# C ошибка Segmentation fault

Tags: c, указатели, malloc, segmentation-fault

При запуске возвращает исключение на строке (61, 62, 63).
Не знаю в чем проблема, вроде и память под указатель выделил.
Но все равно не работает

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void creat2a(int** array);
void printm(int** matrix, int n, int m);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int n = 5, m = 7, i, j;
    int** matrix = (int**) calloc (n, sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*) calloc (m, sizeof(int));
    creat2a(matrix);
    

    printf("Исходная матрица:\n");
    printm(matrix, n, m);

    return 0;
}

void creat2a(int** array)
{
    int n = 5, m = 7, i, j, temp;
    int* element = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            int* element = array[i * m + j];
            temp = rand() % 99 + 1;
            switch (rand() % 3)
            {
                case 0: * element = temp; break;
                case 1: * element = temp * -1; break;
                case 2: * element = temp * 5 % 100; break;
            }

        }
    }
}

void printm(int** matrix, int n, int m)
{ // вывод двумерного массива на экран.
    int end = n - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i == end) printf("\\ "); else
        i == 0 ? printf("/ ") : printf("| ");
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        printf("%3d ", matrix[i][j]);
        if (i == end) printf("/"); else
        i == 0 ? printf("\\\n") : printf("|\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Строку самим считать?

Answer (score 0):

Выделяли память так :

```
int** matrix = (int**) calloc (n, sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
  matrix[i] = (int*) calloc (m, sizeof(int));
```

выводите на экран так :

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    printf("%3d ", matrix[i][j]);
```

а читаете по старинке. Правильнее :

```
int* element = //array[i * m + j];
          & array[i][j] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось самостоятельно, разобраться.

```
void creat2a(int** array)
    {
        int n = 5, m = 7, i, j, temp;
        int* element = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            int* element = array[i];
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                temp = rand() % 99 + 1;
                switch (rand() % 3)
                {
                    case 0: element[j] = temp; break;
                    case 1: element[j] = temp; break;
                    case 2: element[j] = temp * -1; break;
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
```